# Does ui-grid have the same icons for sorting as ng-grid?

Tags: angularjs, sorting, glyphicons, angular-ui-grid

I upgraded from ng-grid to ui-grid. The grid works fine including sorting, filtering and moving. I even have the correct font files and have them mapped properly. However I have no icons what so ever. I am not even getting "funky chars" because of the missing font file.

To show the order of the sort, nothing in the pagination buttons, nothing in the header row and nothing to show there is a dropdown menu. Does any one know if "ui" vs "ng" they removed anything like that?

How do I get the pagination to show something for the user to see and how do i show icons for the sort direction in the headers?

Comment: Which version? Just looking at http://ui-grid.info/ it seems those chevrons are set with classes ui-grid-icon-up-dir / ui-grid-icon-down-dir. Did  you include the correct css ? (either ui-grid.min.css or ui-grid-unstable.css)

Comment: The version is angular-ui-grid v: 3.0.0-rc.20, and yes i have included the proper css, however it looks as if those classes are not defined in the styles. For instance my grid is calling this style : ui-grid-icon-up-dir but when I search ui-grid.css I cannot find it. At this point I am thinking i need to get those rules somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [current UI-Grid CSS](http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid-unstable.css) file definitely has that `ui-grid-icon-up-dir` class; here's the relevant snippet:

```
/* '썘' */
.ui-grid-icon-up-dir:before {
  content: '\c359';
}
```

Since the `ui-grid-icon-up-dir` class is not defined in the CSS file you examined, that file must be outdated (perhaps a cache- or path-related issue?)  To test that theory, you could try temporarily changing your CSS link to the [current UI-Grid CSS](http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid-unstable.css) to see if those icons appear:

```
<link href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid-unstable.css" rel="stylesheet">
```